# find changes with Multiprocess between 2 huge lists

Tags: python, ruby, pandas, multithreading, multiprocessing

i'm trying to compare 2 huge lists and find which lines are not in the second list.

for Example :

**List1:**
a
b
c
d

**List2:**
a
g
h
d

**result:**
b
c

b c in list1 but not in list 2.

the size of list1 is 60GB of lines.
the size of list2 is 76GB of lines.

when trying to load the lists the process is getting killed because of out-of-memory.

I tried using pandas but it takes forever, I would like to add some multi-processing to speed up things but I cant make it happen.
here is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd

for chunk in pd.read_csv("/folder/list1",chunksize=1000,header=None):
    for ind in chunk.index:
        flag =0
        for chunk1 in pd.read_csv("/folder/list2",chunksize=1000,header=None):
            for ind1 in chunk1.index:
                if chunk[0][ind] == chunk1[0][ind1]:
                    flag = 1
                    break
    if flag == 0:
            with open(f"result", 'a+') as file:
            file.write(chunk[0][ind] + '\n')
```

Comment: Can we see your attempts on the multiprocess solution? Are you looking for working code or just for a general algorithm (pseudocode) that would do the job?

Comment: are the lists sorted in the files?

Comment: looking for solution, my code didnt work at all. i will post it asap.

the lists not sorted @DaSong

Comment: I suggest [sorting the files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120096/how-to-sort-big-files) first. When the files are sorted you would basically only need two pointers, one for each file, and only need to iterate both files once.

Comment: still on a large list like this it won't change much.
does multiprocessing can help here ?

Comment: It would be helpful it you could provide more information about the application. In particular: a) on average, how many characters are in each line (e.g. 10-20 or 100-200)? b) Roughly what percentage of lines in file 1 do you expect to be in file 2 (e.g, 50% or less than 0.1%)? c) does the application permit a small number of lines in file 1 to be reported as being in file 2 when those lines in fact are not in file 2?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind: _Don't iterate over the rows_, work with sets. E.g. `chunk_set = set(chunk.iloc[:, 0].values)`  in first chunk-loop and then check for `len(chunk_set & set(chunk1.iloc[:, 0].values)) > 0` in second chunk-loop. (I'm assuming that the dataframes only have one column and that the content of the columns is hashable.)

Comment: What kind stuff is in the files? Is there a chance to compress the identity information of a row? At least approximative, such that there are a lot of non-costly pre-checks that rule out identity and only very few that need to go further?

Comment: a) 100-200
b) 50%-60%
c) no, its must be accurate.
@CarySwoveland

Comment: all of the lines are paths like this:
folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/file @Timus

Comment: I would suggest to split it into sub-problems. Keep `list2` complete, divide `list1` in `N` parts, where `N` is the number of processes you want to spawn. For each partition of `list1`, check if it is in the complete `list2`, write the output to a file (for each process!). In the end, merge all the files from your processes and you should be done. Would that work?

Comment: Sound good,
i'm not sure how many processes should I do, or how to merge the files.
should I give the files a different names?
how the chunks will be part of it? and not get out of memory. @André

Comment: If, on average, each lines contain 100-200 characters, the file sizes would be 6TB-12TB for file 1 and 7.6TB-15.2TB for file 2. Those are mighty big files. Are you sure they are that large?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach in Ruby. The idea is to create a hash whose keys are hash codes of the lines of file #2 and whose values are arrays of offsets into the file that begin a line having the hash code given by the key. Most of these arrays will of course contain a single offset, but we must account for the fact that it is possible that distinct strings have the same hash code, a possibility that is evident from the fact that the number of unique hash codes is finite whereas the number of unique strings is infinite.

It is conceivable that file #2 is so large that this hash cannot be held in memory. If that is the case the approach described below would have to be modified to hold the content of the hash in a database, indexed by the keys.

First let's create an example of file #2.

```
str =<<~_
Now is the time
for all good coders
to come to the aid
of their fellow coders
_
```

```
F2_NAME = 'test'
```

```
File.write(FNAME, str)
  #=> 78
```

Suppose we were to compute the following.

```
require 'set'
hash_codes_in_F2 = File.foreach(F2_NAME)
                       .with_object(Set.new) { |line, s| s << line.chomp.hash }
  #=> #<Set: {2098464159550983171, -1174471330590153942,
  #           -2185914657312873106, 4309024537421084150}>
```

We have computed, for example:

```
"Now is the time".hash
  #=> 2098464159550983171
```

See [Set::new](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-c-new) and [String#hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-hash).

For a moment assume that every string has a unique hash code, which we know may in general not be true. We could simply compute the hash code for each line in file 1 and see if it is a member of the set `hash_codes_in_F2`, each lookup being very fast, equivalent to determining if a hash has a particular key. The line from file 1 is a line in F2 if and only if its hash code is an element of that set.

Now let's modify this approach to recognize that two strings may have the same hash code. Instead of a set we will construct a hash.

First, we need a helper method.

```
def a_repeat?(line, locs, f, loc)
  locs.any? do |l|
    pos = l
    line == f.gets.chomp
  end
  pos = loc
end
```

Here:

- `line` is a string;
- `locs` is an array of offsets in file 2 that begin a (chomped) line having a given hash code;
- f is the handle of file 2, which was already opened for reading; and
- `loc` is the current location in file 2 when the method is called, needed to reposition the file pointer before the method returns.

We see that this method determines if the (chomped) string `line` equals any lines in file 2 that begin at the offsets given by `locs`.

See [Enumerable#any?])(https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F), [IO#pos](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-i-pos), [IO#gets](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-i-gets) and [IO#pos=](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-i-pos-3D).

We may now construct the hash `hash_codes`.

```
hash_codes = {}
f = File.new(F2_NAME)
until f.eof?
  loc = pos
  line = f.gets.chomp
  code = line.hash
  if hash_codes.key?(code)
    if a_repeat?(line, hash_codes[code], f, loc)
      hash_codes[code] << loc
    end
  else
    hash_codes[code] = [loc]
  end
end
```

```
hash_codes
  #=> {2098464159550983171=>[0], -1174471330590153942=>[16],
  #    -2185914657312873106=>[36], 4309024537421084150=>[55]}
```

Note the following.

```
[0, 16, 36, 55].each do |offset|
  f.pos = offset
  puts f.gets.chomp
end
```

displays

```
Now is the time
for all good coders
to come to the aid
of their fellow coders
```

If file 2 had a line starting at, say, offset 67, that had hash code `-2185914657312873106` but was not the string `"to come to the aid"` the key `-2185914657312873106` would have the value `[36, 67]`.

Notice that file 2 is still open.

We now merely loop through each (chomped) line of file 1.

Suppose a line of file 1 were as follows:

```
line = "to go to the mall"
```

We then compute

```
code = line.hash
  #=> 1233397236348202523
```

As `hash_code.key?(code) #=> false` we conclude that `line` is not a line of file 2. Now suppose the line of file 1 were

```
line = "to come to the aid"
```

We compute

```
code = line.hash
  #=> -2185914657312873106
```

and because `hash_code.key?(code) #=> true`, we compute

```
locs = hash_code[code]
  #=> [36]
```

This tells us that there is a line (or multiple identical lines) in file 2 with hash code `-2185914657312873106`. We must still verify, however, that the two lines are identical, so for each element of `locs`, `l`, we need to compute

```
f.pos = l
line == f.gets.chomp
```

Here that would be

```
f.pos = 36
line == f.gets.chomp
  #=> true
```

telling us that that line in file 1 is in file 2.